# Linux-RT patches

Tags: linux-kernel, rtos, linux-rt

I am getting started with Linux-RT and browsing in the Internet I have realized that isn't the same "full Linux-RT" and "PREEMPT_RT kernel config". Which is the difference?

I am working in a project and need a RTOS, so I decided to get Linux.

Comment: Why would you think you need lower interrupt latency than what is already provided by the kernel without the RT patches?

Comment: _"need a RTOS, so I decided to get Linux"_ is non-sequitur.  Linux is not an RTOS - even with PREEMT_RT.  You'd use it if your application needed Linux services  or POSIX code reuse (some library you needed perhaps) and and some "soft" real-time requirements, and of course your platform has plenty of memory and a fast processor.  Also if you don't care about taking several tens of seconds to boot.

Comment: ... Also did you mean Linux-RT and not RTLinux?